# UDP input plugin fails with SocketError: bind: name or service not known

Tags: elasticsearch, udp, logstash

This is my logstash config file. I want to use multiple config files by using the type.

```
input {
  udp { 
    port => 62555
    type => 4444 
  } 
}
output {
   if [type] == "4444" {
   }
}
```

The error is:

```
←[33mUDP listener died {:exception=>#<SocketError: bind: name or service not   known>, :backtrace=>["org/jruby/ext/socket/RubyUDPSocket.java:157:in `bind'","F:/elasticsearch-2.3.1/logstash-2.3.4/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/logstash-input-udp-2.0.5/lib/logstash/inputs/udp.rb:67:in `udp_listener'", "F:/elasticsearch-2.3.1/logstash-2.3.4/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/logstash-input-udp2.0.5/lib/logstash/inputs/udp.rb:50:in `run'", "F:/elasticsearch-2.3.1/logstash-2.3.4/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/logstash-core-2.3.4-java/lib/logstash/pipeline.rb:342:in `inputworker'", "F:/elasticsearch2.3.1/logstash-2.3.4/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/logstash-core-2.3.4-java/lib/logstash/pipeline.rb:336:in `start_input'"], :level=>:warn}←[0m
```

Comment: Could you add the error message?

Comment: i have added the error in question

Comment: Apparently the error message is caused by a problem with opening the port

Comment: how i can solve this error i tried many ports in it but nothing is working

Comment: I have no experience with udp on windows, but perhaps you can check on the side of your firewall.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `type` option for the udp input plugin expects a string (cf [documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-inputs-udp.html#plugins-inputs-udp-type)):

> **type**
>   Value type is string
>   There is no default value for this setting.

So you need to add `"` around your `type` option.

The port is a mandatory option for the udp input, if you have problem with it, you need to change the configuration of your server.